# Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11264 bytes)

Tags: apache, php

I'm trying to upload file using simple form. Size of file is 1.37 MB.
After page reload, i get this error:

```
Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 11264 bytes)
```

This is from `phpinfo()`:

```
Directive        Local Value    Master Value
memory_limit     32M            32M
```

max upload file which i did some time ago is 25MB.

This is my php.ini:

```
[PHP]

; Maximum allowed size for uploaded files.
upload_max_filesize = 25M

; Maximum size of POST data that PHP will accept.
post_max_size = 25M


;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; Resource Limits ;
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

; Maximum execution time of each script, in seconds
max_execution_time = 600

; Maximum amount of time each script may spend parsing request data
max_input_time = 600

; Maximum amount of memory a script may consume (8MB)
memory_limit = 32M
```

Comment: Do you process this file somehow? for example image resizing can easily drive you to this error.

Comment: You have already found the php.ini. To increase the memory limit, replace the `32` in the line which begins with `memory_limit` with a higher number. Afterwards, restart Apache.

Comment: @Carsten rising memory limit is not the best solution ;)

Comment: Well, maybe, maybe not. Depends on what miszczu is doing in their code. :)

Comment: You need to show the code that processes the image, that's most likely where the problem lies.

Comment: Yes, script is trying to resize it. Resize and upload script wasn't made by me.

Comment: Thank you all, I just change memory limit to 64mb and it works fine. I just do not understand why people give minus for (I think reasonable) question - less people read those questions and less chance to get the answer or error reason.

Comment: You have just put a band-aid on the problem.  At first glance, processing a 1.5Mb file should not require a huge amount of memory.  Experience says you will run into this problem again... What are you going to do, raise it to 128Mb ?

Comment: I hope not. On website users are uploading 2 types of files: images and pdf documents. There is no problem with pdf, because i'm moving file to destination location only. With image script resize it and save original and resized image. I haven't seen script which resize image, because I'm using cms and just add additional functionality. But I think file won't be bigger than 2 mb. What would you suggest? Do you think resize (or any other) script is written badly and it take too much memory? If yes, how can i check it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use other script to file resize and if it wont help rise memory limit and if you cant do it upload smaller images. No other option.